# Lines and Math Processing Error in a page while editing a deleted answer

Tags: bug

While I was editing an answer that I had deleted,  it displayed with lines and  a Math processing error

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

This affected all the other answers to the same question and the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156462/752) itself.

Another screenshot:

[image]

---

The strange thing is that it has occurred, as far as I've seen, with this page only.

**What may have happen?**

The browser was Firefox 13.0 on Windows 7.

*Added*. Also the same problem with IE 9.

**Added 2.** *I **deleted all the text** of my answer* and  wrote "Deleted to test a bug. Deleted to test a bug. Deleted to test a bug." *and ...  **the malfunction disappeared***.

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/mathjax-bug-upon-page-refresh) and [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4256/suspicious-voting-behavior-and-the-vote-anomaly-detection-script?cb=1) for more information.

Comment: @Davide Cervone Thanks. So, it may there be two causes.

Comment: I have rolled my answer back to revision 1 and it's OK.

Comment: The second link in my earlier comment was wrong.  It should have been [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/math-processing-error-and-other-issues-with-mathjax-in-safari?lq=1).  Must have copied the wrong link accidentally.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @DavideCervone Thanks. It's explained now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour has already been reported in the folowing two questions, whose links are provided by Davide Cervone in two comments.

[MathJax bug upon page refresh](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/mathjax-bug-upon-page-refresh)

[Math processing error and other issues with MathJax in Safari](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/math-processing-error-and-other-issues-with-mathjax-in-safari?lq=1)